# using vb.net to set file attributes

Tags: .net, vb.net

I would like to know how can I set attributes for a file in vb.net

when I open command prompt and I type this I can set attrib

```
attrib +a +h +s test.txt
```

how exactly do I do this on vb.net

Comment: Use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.attributes(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Press F2...type "attributes" press button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
File.SetAttributes(path, File.GetAttributes("test.txt") Or FileAttributes.Archive)
File.SetAttributes(path, File.GetAttributes("test.txt") Or FileAttributes.Hidden)
File.SetAttributes(path, File.GetAttributes("test.txt") Or FileAttributes.System)
```

Answer (score -2):

Private Sub GAttrib (fpath As String)

'To get attributes:
'fpath must contain the full path and file name ex: C:\Test.txt
MsgBox(File.GetAttributes(fpath).ToString)

To set/change attributes:
File.SetAttributes(fpath, FileAttributes.Archive Or FileAttributes.Hidden Or FileAttributes.System Or FileAttributes.ReadOnly)

'You can use a single attribute or a combination like above.
'If you want to check the new attribute(s) repeat the msgbox
MsgBox(File.GetAttributes(fpath).ToString)

End Sub